# Downgrade Gradle from 3.3 to 2.14.1

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

Long story short: My android phone keeps disconnecting from ADB.  I was told to update android studio, did that.  I open my project in Intellij and try to run on android and I get an error:

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 48.986 secs

Error: /Users/me/Desktop/comp/Development/comp-ionic/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

My first thought is that my gradle is the wrong version.  For this specific app, I need to use gradle version `2.14.1`.

When I type `gradle -v` I'm getting version 3.3.

Is there a way to delete/downgrade gradle from 3.3 to 2.14.1?

Or is this another problem?

Comment: The USB getting disconnected, I face it too, thought it was a hardware issue, anyway now I use wireless adb :D

Comment: I've been trying wireless as well, so far it's alright, just takes a bit longer

Comment: OMG, so is this a software issue? I doubted my poor USB port and cable :D

Comment: I purchased 3 different USB cables...  I've read many forums, they keep saying do a full uninstall and then install the latest android studio...  did that, still disconnecting and now having this problem...

Comment: I've upvoted the question then, we'll see if we get a solution :D

Comment: Why don't you run gradle with the `-stacktrace` option, so that you could actually see the reason for the problem and not guess that you may need to downgrade?

Comment: @yole, I'd love for that to work, I guess I'm doing that wrong?  When in this project, I run `ionic run android` and if I add `--stacktrace` to it, I don't get any extra information.  Am I running the wrong command?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're using the gradle wrapper, then there'll be a folder in your project named "gradle" with a subfolder named "wrapper", inside that, there are 2 files:
- gradle-wrapper.jar
- gradle-wrapper.properties

Open "gradle-wrapper.properties" and change the place where it says "3.3" to "2.14.1". Then sync gradle, and it will automatically download 2.14.1.

If you're using the new 2.3 Android Studio, you HAVE to use gradle wrapper 3.3, as its the minimum supported gradle wrapper version. If so, then you'll have to download Android Studio 2.2, or fix whatever issue you have in your project that needs gradle wrapper version 2.14.1.

To get more information about whatever the issue is, try running this:
./gradlew clean assemble -stacktrace

That will clean your project, try and compile it, and if/when it fails, it will show you a stacktrace of the error.

Comment: >If you're using the new 2.3 Android Studio, you HAVE to use gradle wrapper 3.3<  I will try to get 2.2 again and see if this can fix it

Comment: If it does work with Android Studio 2.2, that's a really bad fix though. Some day soon Android Studio 2.3 will be the stable version, and then you'll be stuck on an outdated version that will never get updates. It would be better to fix your issues and use Gradle Wrapper 3.3

Comment: For now, downgrading android studio was the fix.  I will talk to my team about the gradle issues though.  Thank you!

Comment: how do you get the gradle wrapper?

Answer (score 5):

What you should do is to change the `gradle build tools` version to the one that matches your gradle version. According to [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle) you can set the gradle to **2.14.1** by changing build tools to lower than `1.0.0`.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'// For gradle 2.2.1 - 2.3

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

**Notice:**  if you keep checking the mentioned link you'll see **Higher is better** for gradle.

Answer (score 1):

For me, `Android Studio > File > Invalidate Caches / Restart` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when upgrading to Android Studio 2.3.1. There is something funky about Gradle 3.3 (It fails by "java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: destinationDir=null at com.google.common.collect.CollectPreconditions.checkEntryNotNull(CollectPreconditions.java:33)").
Good news: seems like the current most recent version (3.5) works.

Go to File|Project Structure|Project, and use these versions:
Gradle version=3.5
Android Plugin version=2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I update the Android Studio version to *3.3 Canary 4*, then update the gradle plugin, and the project stops working.

I do not know how to restore my AS to the previous state, nighter the gradle plugin.

But just with this command, the project now works, for me: `gradlew clean assemble -stacktrace`, in terminal tab in AS.